# Using tkFont from tkinter to identify if a font (Helvetica-Light) is available/installed

Tags: python, django, tkinter

We have a Django application, and we utilize `HTML` to `pdf` generation tool to build pdf documents. We have run into problems with fonts not existing on the server converting HTML to pdfs, and I want to add a unit test that can verify if a font exists on the hosting server.

From what I have learned, I should be using Tkinter's `tkFont` module to get available fonts list, and confirm the fonts we are using are found within this list.

```
class VerifyFontsExistOnServer(BaseTransactionTestCase):
    def test_if_font_exists(self):
        import Tkinter
        import tkFont
        Tkinter.Tk()
        installed_font_families =[i for i in tkFont.families()
                                  if 'Helvetica' in i
                                  or 'Courier' in i
                                  or 'DejaVuSerif' in i
                                  or 'OCRA' in i]

        for font in installed_font_families:
            log.info('{0}'.format(font))
```

But when I list the items out, I get `Helvetica` as a font, but not Helvetica-Light. I believe this is part of this family, but is there a way to identify if this particular font style of the family exists?

Comment: This might be a dumb question... I  just typed import tkFont, and it found it... is tkFont a built in module to python like io?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a shell based method to call the fc-list terminal command:

```
def verify_fonts_are_installed_for_statements():
    import subprocess
    from os import path
    potential_locations = [
        '/usr/bin/fc-list',
        '/usr/sbin/fc-list',
        '/usr/local/sbin/fc-list',
        '/usr/local/bin/fc-list',
    ]
    valid_path = None
    for file_path in potential_locations:
        if path.exists(file_path):
            valid_path = file_path
            break
    if valid_path is None:
        raise IOError('could not find fc-list to verify fonts exist.')

    cmd = [valid_path]
    output = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]

    if 'Helvetica Neue' not in output:
        raise FontNotInstalledException('Helvetica Neue')
    if 'Courier' not in output:
        raise FontNotInstalledException('Courier')

    log.debug('Courier and Helvetica Neue were found to be installed.')
```